# How to create a signature for Netsuite using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, request, get, netsuite, signature

I'm trying to make a "GET" request in Apps Script to retrieve information from Netsuite, and I'm having problems with the signature. I've been reading documentation about it (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_157652798351.html) but I haven't been able to create the signature. Every time I run the code (below) i get this message:

```
{"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}
```

My theory is that I'm doing something wrong at the moment of encoding the text and key parameters; I'm not sure which of them should be encoded into UTF-8, and which should be encoded using Base64.
Also, I don't understand how the key and text parameters should be constructed: I've read that the key parameter must be a concatenation of the consumer secret and the token secret, and also I have to encode them (the problem is that I don't understand how, and whether it's after or before the creation of the signature). Documentation says the text parameter, should be something like this:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2F1234567.restlets.api.netsuite.com%2Frest%2Frequesttoken&oauth_callback%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmy.example.com%252FTBA%252F%253FcallbackRequest%26oauth_consumer_key%3D60712990bc09623786e7047c226bcb3f86d49dca0b04efc21001dc76d97a81f5%26oauth_nonce%3DbUvpxBX93OWo0FLswq5M%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1575998103%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26role%3D45678
```

I've already done that, the thing is that I want to know if I have to make another enconding stuff. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function getRequest(){
  
  let url = "";
  let marcaDeTiempo = timeEstampd(); //this is the timestamp
  let text = "";
  let consumerSecret = "";
  let tokenSecret = "";
  let key = consumerSecret + "&" + tokenSecret;
  
  let signature = crypto(text, key);
  
  var formData = {

  
    'Authorization':  `OAuth realm=\"\",oauth_consumer_key=\"\",oauth_token=\"\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\",oauth_timestamp=\"${marcaDeTiempo}\",oauth_nonce=\"\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"${signature}\"`,
  'Cookie': '',
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
  };

  
  var options = {
    method : 'get',
    headers : formData,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 

  Logger.log(response);
}


//function to create the signature
function crypto(message, secret){
  var byteSignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, secret);
  // convert byte array to hex string Charset.UTF_8
  var signature = byteSignature.reduce(function(str,chr){
    chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
    return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
  },''
  );

  //Logger.log(typeof signature);
  return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(byteSignature);
}


//function to generate timestamp
function timeEstampd(){
  const currentTime = new Date();
  return currentTime.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up an OAuth2 authentication flow and use the generated access token for authentication instead. https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2